# The expression of the fine-structure constant post-May 2019

Tags: physical-constants, absolute-units

Those of us who are engineers were never fond of the common expression from physicists that

$$ \alpha = \frac{e^2}{\hbar c} $$

implying that the units of the elementary charge are in "$\sqrt{hc}$".

Those of us that are a little more *anal* (can't spell "analysis" without *"anal"*) about dimension of physical *"stuff"* and units know that the complete expression for the fine-structure constant is

$$ \alpha = \frac{e^2}{(4 \pi \varepsilon_0) \hbar c} $$

but the seasoned physicists are thinking in terms of [electrostatic cgs units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units#Electrostatic_units_(ESU)) where the unit of charge is defined so that the  Coulomb constant $k_\mathrm{e} = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}$ is set to **dimensionless** 1.

That seemed okay before May 20, 2019 when all of the *"variables"* in $\varepsilon_0 = \frac{1}{c^2 \mu_0}$ were defined constants and it didn't seem to be a whoop to use a different definition of a dimensionful constant $\varepsilon_0$.

But now $\varepsilon_0$ is a ***measured*** universal constant that is expressed with an error specification and is derived from $\alpha$ anyway.  Are these HEP physicists gonna continue saying $\alpha = \frac{e^2}{\hbar c}$ or will they have to be more proper with their use of *"constants"* and dimensionality?  Will they continue to say that the units of the elementary charge are "$\sqrt{hc}$"?

Comment: HEP theorists (at least all the ones I know) usually just write $e = \sqrt{4 \pi \alpha}$ using natural units rather than electrostatic cgs units.

Comment: **i like that.** (but [Wikipedia says that these same HEP folks say the unit of charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge#As_a_unit) are $\sqrt{hc}$.  maybe that article is crap.  I wish that Planck Units were completely rationalized so that $c = \hbar = 4 \pi G = \varepsilon_0 = 1$.  I think eventually the HEP guys and cosmologists and TOE guys will eventually come to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My prediction is that the 2019 metrological redefinitions will have absolutely no impact on how theoretical physicists use natural units. They will continue to think of $\hbar$ and $c$ as $1$, and of $e$ and $\alpha$ as dimensionless, and there will be nothing improper about doing so. Most will continue to think of SI units as a bizarre historical monstrosity.

Comment: +1, i'll see if there are other answers before you get a check mark.

Comment: but SI is getting better.